How can I import a software installer (.exe) into the wordpress media library
I do not really want this available on the web interface and am content with having to ssh into the wordpress instance to do it, both to transfer the file in ( often large ) and to do the
"wp media import testinstaller.exe" command on the server
to do it.  I would set permission on the file  to root:? r--r--r--
This is for a password protected site used by beta testers to download test versions of a windows app from.
Thanks

You might receive a better response at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

You can't upload executable files to WordPress.com sites, but you can upload and link them from sites that allow them, such as Dropbox or Google Drive.

well have that sorted - but next is I need to figure out how to figure out how to sign an installer for windows built with the NSIS installer maker - an unsigned one seems to be detected as a virus by a number of scanners :O
